# whats wrong with this php mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php

Atomic Number
Latin
English
Abbreviation

* check the variables for content */

`/*** a list of filters ***/
$filters = array(
'searchtext' => array( 'filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK, 'options'  => 'mysql_real_escape_string'),
'fieldname'  => array( 'filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK, 'options'  => 'mysql_real_escape_string')
);

/*** escape all POST variables ***/
$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filters);

/*** check the values are not empty ***/
if(empty($input['fieldname']) || empty($input['searchtext']))
    {
    echo 'Invalid search';
    }
else
    {
    /*** mysql hostname ***/
    $hostname = 'localhost';

    /*** mysql username ***/
    $username = 'username';

    /*** mysql password ***/
    $password = 'password';

    /*** mysql database name ***/
    $dbname = 'periodic_table';

    /*** connect to the database ***/
    $link = @mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

    /*** check if the link is a valid resource ***/
    if(is_resource($link))
        {
        /*** select the database we wish to use ***/
        if(mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) === TRUE)
            {
            /*** sql to SELECT information***/
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM elements WHERE %s = '%s'", $input['fieldname'], $input['searchtext']);

        /*** echo the sql query ***/
        echo '<h3>'.$sql.'</h3>';

            /*** run the query ***/
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            /*** check if the result is a valid resource ***/
            if(is_resource($result))
                {
                /*** check if we have more than zero rows ***/
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) !== 0)
                    {
            echo '<table>';
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                        echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$row['atomicnumber'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['latin'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['english'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['abbr'].'</td>
                        </tr>';
                        }
            echo '</table>';
                    }
                else
                    {
                    /*** if zero results are found.. ***/
                    echo 'Zero results found';
                    }
                }
            else
                {
                /*** if the resource is not valid ***/
                'No valid resource found';
                }
            }
        /*** if we are unable to select the database show an error ****/
        else
            {
            echo 'Unable to select database '.$dbname;
            }
        /*** close the connection ***/
        mysql_close($link);
        }
    else
        {
        /*** if we fail to connect ***/
        echo 'Unable to connect';
        }
    }
}`

else
    {
    echo 'Please Choose An Element';
    }
?>

I got this code from phppro.org tutorials site and i tried to run it. It gives 
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established. ....
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)....

I went to php.net and look it up "Note: A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE  is returned. If link_identifier  isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used."

My questions are:
1-why they put  single quotation around mysql_real_escape_string ?
2-They should establish a connection first, then use the $filter array statement with mysql_real_escape_string ?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Nope, the whole filter\_input\_array() thingy is supposed to invoke real\_escape\_string on each element of \_POST and store the result in $input. _If_ it worked as intended there would be no sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: @VolkerK So what? real_escape_string is not a magic spell that makes you "safe".

Comment: I mean take a closer look at the WHERE clause ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is not with mysql_real_escape_string.  Your problem is with the fact that you don't have a connection to a server.  Do you have a database 'periodic_table' running locally with 'username' and 'password' for your login credentials?

Comment: Move the `$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filters);` line after `if(is_resource($link))`

Comment: Man, even phppro tutorials does not work so i guess no one on is PRO and why would people put up tutorials that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

1. they used function name as a parameter for the another function.
2. Yes

Answer (score 0):

I think mysql_real_escape_string needs a connection so it knows what charset is used.

also in php, single quotes are faster then double quotes as php doesn't have to process the contents of thr string looking for $varname etc.